# Get all <images> within <subject> with jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I'm using jQuery Ajax call to fetch a list of images. Right now it works but gets all images within the XML file. How can I change my code so that it gets all images for a given subject, instead of showing all the images in all subjects.

So for each 'subject' tag I want to list all 'image' tags.

I know I have to change line 11 with the jQuery

```
$(data).find('image').each(function(){
```

Full jQuery function

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#ARTH1520").live('pagebeforecreate', function() {
        $.get('data/ARTH1520.xml',function(data){
            $('.content').empty();
            $(data).find('subject').each(function(){
                var $subject = $(this);
                var html = '<div class="data">';                      
                html += '<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-theme="b"><h3>' + $subject.attr('title') + '</h3>';
                html += '<ul data-role="listview">';

                    $(data).find('image').each(function(){
                    var $image = $(this);
                    html += '<li><img src="' + $image.attr('img') + '" />';
                    html += '<h3>' + $image.attr('title') + '</h3><p>' + $image.attr('description') + '</p></li>';

                    }); 

                html += '</ul>';
                html += '</div></div>';
                $('#result').append(html).trigger( "create" );
                $('#result .loading').remove();
            });                        
        });
        });
    </script>
```

XML File

```
<subjects>
<subject title="At History One">
    <images>
        <image title="Mona Lisa" img="lisa.jpg" id="s1i1" description="image 1"></image>
        <image title="" img="" id="s1i2" description=""></image>
    </images>
</subject>  
<subject title="Renaissance">
        <images>
        <image title="" img="" id="s1i3" description=""></image>
    </images>
</subject>
```

Comment: Did you try `$subject.find('image').each` ?

Comment: No but it works with that, thanks. Add as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$subject.find('image').each(function(){ }` to iterate through the images inside the subject tag. You have to replace the line 11 as you mentioned.